# FlipView Adapter not Updating

Tags: java, android, flipview

The adapter of a flipview is set onCreate. Everything works fine. The user is meant to select some items on another activity which would update the items on the flipview. I implemented this by changing the adapter of the flipView when onResume is called and the dismiss activity is the selectionActivity. The code is executed but it does not reflect on the flipView items.

What i do on onCreate

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flip_main, container, false);
            mFlipView = (FlipView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.flip_view);

            mAdapter = new FlipAdapter(getActivity(),getHomeItems(), getFragmentManager());
            mAdapter.setCallback(this);
            mFlipView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mFlipView.setOnFlipListener(this);
            if (isFirstShown) {
                mFlipView.peakNext(false);
                isFirstShown = false;
            }
            mFlipView.setOverFlipMode(OverFlipMode.RUBBER_BAND);
            mFlipView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
            mFlipView.setOnOverFlipListener(this);
            return rootView;
        }
```

what is called after the user makes selection

```
FlipAdapterTest mAdapter = new FlipAdapterTest(getActivity(), getHomeItems(), getFragmentManager());
    mFlipView.removeAllViews();
    mFlipView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```